Most recommended approach to handle 404 errors to /admin/host/ping for my ASP.NET MVC application hosted in Azure app services
We have an ASP.NET MVC application (in .NET framework 4.8.1) hosted in Azure App Services. We have enabled the automatic scaling-out option from the Azure portal (Web App > Settings > Scale Out). We noticed continuous error logs in the application insights logs mentioning the ping to the path /admin/host/ping as shown below.
app service ping errors in app insights
As per the suggestion in the MS doc, as added below, we were able to understand that this is not an issue for the application hosted in the app services.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-automatic-scaling?tabs=azure-portal#why-does-appservicehttplogs-have-log-entries-similar-to-adminhostping-with-a-404-status
However, the volume of error logs it is creating (around 10k daily) is a bit of a concern for us to monitor the logs from application insights.
My question is about the most recommended approach to handle this issue for web applications hosted in Azure App services which will help us to avoid the unnecessary logs added in the application insights.
Someone, please suggest the best solutions in practice.
I have tried the solutions mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1457153/seeing-a-lot-of-404s-to-admin-host-ping-after-turn
and also the solutions Whats pinging my Azure App every 13 seconds (admin/host/ping).
I want to stay with the automatic scaling-out feature. However the recommended approach did not work.

What is the version of your App?

I am not getting any Exceptions as you mentioned. Need to check your code configuration. If possible, please share your code repo.

My app uses the .NET framework 4.8.1. The exceptions occur when the auto-scaling feature is enabled in the Azure app service, and the app really scales due to an increase in requests. I checked by stopping the auto-scaling feature, and these error logs stopped.
And sorry, I cannot share the code/repo as it is private.

The /admin/host/ping logs in your Application Insights may be caused by changes in workload or scaling activity.
App Service Automatic Scaling periodically checks the /admin/host/ping endpoint as part of its health checks. These checks don’t impact the app’s availability or scaling. You can safely ignore them or filter them out in the code if needed.
Refer this doc to know how to filter out specific logs.
Create a telemetry processor class IgnorePingRequestTelemetryProcessor.cs
add the below lines to it to ignore the /admin/host/ping logs.
 public void Process(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        if (telemetry is RequestTelemetry request && request.Url.AbsolutePath.Contains("/admin/host/ping"))
        {
            
            return;
        }

Complete IgnorePingRequestTelemetryProcessor.cs:
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;

public class IgnorePingRequestTelemetryProcessor : ITelemetryProcessor
{
    private readonly ITelemetryProcessor _next;

    public IgnorePingRequestTelemetryProcessor(ITelemetryProcessor next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public void Process(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        if (telemetry is RequestTelemetry request &&
            request.Url.AbsolutePath.Contains("/admin/host/ping"))
        {
           
            return;
        }

        _next.Process(telemetry);
    }
}

Register this telemetry processor in your program.cs file
program.cs:
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryProcessorFactory>(sp =>
    new TelemetryProcessorFactory(sp, next => new IgnorePingRequestTelemetryProcessor(next)));
var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.Run();

By implementing filters, we can exclude unwanted logs from Application Insights.


Thanks for your answer. However, I wanted to know if filtering the logs is the most recommended way to handle this. Or adding this route to the application is a better solution. Or there is something else to do.
I did not find any recommendation from Microsoft side. That is why just got confused. Thanks again.
